# Does slowing negative and positive movements of exercises build muscle

Tags: exercise-technique, bodyweight-exercises, muscle-mass

I've heard that the perfect form of bodyweight exercises need to be slow. For instance, in pull ups, I have to go up in 2 seconds, pause a second at the top position and then go down in 2 seconds.
Which goal does that technique help, muscle gain or endurance ?

In another words, If I can do 20 fast movement push ups and I want to build more muscle using push ups. Will I gain muscle if I used the technique mentioned above ?

Comment: Not sure about this whole 'time under tension' business, but if you go slow you can't really cheat by swinging the weight. So at least that is a plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that 2 seconds up, 2 seconds down is good technique, and should be followed in most exercises.  If you need momentum to complete the set or to do the exercise then the weight should be reduced, as this is not good form.

In regards to whether it's for muscle gain or endurance, good form should be for both.

To look at muscle growth/endurance you need to look at the number of reps and weights